# Find a web server installed in LAN

Tags: django, dns, webserver, client

My first Django project is suppoesed to run localy for some time before eventually moved to cloud. The goal is that the user will install the application which by turn will install a webserver in his machine, double click the executable(the server) and presto....open a browser start using it. But there is a problem I didn't forsee when I was making my app. The project is supposed to support multi users so everyone should be able to access it from their pc's (connected on the same LAN) just by openning their browsers and entering the web server's address. But that's the problem here. How can i make sure that whatever the IP of the server's machine is or gets after a reboot, the "clients" will always know, or use a name to connect to the server. Can it be done programmatically? Is it worth the trouble?My app is storing some sensitive data that I think by law they need to be protected(encrypted) before getting online, and that's the reason I'm thinking locally right now. Installing a dns at the same time would it be a solution or maybe another problem. I want or my initial thought is the user to be able to just "plug n play", everything done automatically by installation.

EDIT:Trying to be simpler: I have installed a webserver (cherrypy) on a machine on a Lan. I want other machines on lan to be able to go to their browsers type in the ip address (or name) of webserver and log in to my django project. My question is if there is a way to automate this, supposingly server won't be on static ip or dedicated machine for sever, so with every reboot the server's ip will change. Hope I did make more sense now. No code cause I haven't written any. Just nee some pointing to the right direction

Comment: Your question is extremely difficult to read... Furthermore it is not related to a specific programming question... and you did not post a single line of any code... so how should we be able to help?? :(

Comment: It is related to programming, because i am asking if there is a programmatical way to find a webserver in a Lan. There is no code cause I haven't written one yet. It is a question so that I will be able to write some code. What didn't you understand, I could explain better..Sorry I am not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer? Make sure that the "sever" is not on dynamic IP

Even if you are working with DHCP only, you can bind a specific IP to specific server.
Get you sys admin/network manager to help you with this.

If this is not an option, you will have to "build" a solution yourself.
There are some options available.

- You can have a custom `hosts` file that has been placed on shared folder which you will update after every boot with your current IP
- you can build/use service like dynamic IP (dyndns.com and the likes)
- you can build a client side service that will update the `hosts` files when it start or when it gets a "change IP" msg from your server

There are some options, but the best one is to ***make your server IP a fixed one***.

EDIT:
Another option might be to ***use the Windows name*** of the machine to connect to it.
This should work within a Windows Domain Network (As far as I remember, but just give it a test)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Izack, Will do my search and get back to maybe